# Navigation in SwiftUI - App Setup Navigation View flow into a Tab View Navigation flow

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Picking up swift again for the first time in a while and this seems way more difficult than it should be to find a clear answer on the correct way to go about this as it seems like a common scenario for an app.

I need to present the user with a few set up screens (user registration, login, other details) that will only be presented once when first setting up the app.

When finished with this setup process the app should navigate to a Tab View based Home Screen which will be the main navigation throughout the app (with each tab item having its own NavigationView navigation)

Navigating from the setup to the home view with a Navigation Link stays within that initial navigation view hierarchy and I end up with double navigation bars on the Home Screen. I've also tried presenting the setup view as a FullScreenCover, but that didn't seem to fully work correctly either.

I'm avoiding posting code as I want to find the best way this will work for multiple projects, not specifically for what I'm currently working on.

Comment: This question seems more inline with [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Stackoverflow is more [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions about problems and algorithms.